# Regex expression to validate pre and post slash of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create regex expression for string with pre and post slash (/). How to write regex expression for below string

```
"/anystring/"
```

I just wanted to check if string has pre and post slash or not. I have tried `/\/(\w+)/ig/\` but it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a typo: flags must be at the end, and `/` is defined as `\/` in the regex literal. `/\/\w+\//` might suffice since `i` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following if you're looking for any character between the two slashes

```
\/.*\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/qRIxxN/1

Or this if you're looking for only single words

```
\/\w+\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/9sg54S/1

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `startswith` and `endswith` methods of string, instead of using regex

```py
>>> text = "/anystring/"
>>> text.startswith('/') and text.endswith('/')
True
```

For regex, you can use the pattern `\/\w+\/`:

```py
>>> re.match('\/\w+\/', text)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='/anystring/'>
```